# psutil.sensors.temperatures() only delivers {}

Tags: python, ubuntu, psutil

I'm trying to set up a little python script showing me e.g. my current CPU temperature. I imported psutil to do so. As mentioned in the [psutil documentation](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), I tried the command `psutil.sensors_temperatures(fahrenheit=False)`. Nevertheless, the only output of the program is `{}`.

Did I make a mistake or could this be a problem caused by the temperature sensor of my CPU?

Operating system: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Python version: 3.10.12

Thanks for your advice!

edit:

There must be a temperature sensor, because the CPU fan is regulating itself based on the temperature. "Psensor Temperature Monitor" [does not show any other values than CPU usage and free memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfy6l.png).
I also tried to use "lm-sensors", but after a complete scan, no sensors were detected anyways.

Comment: https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.sensors_temperatures
If sensors are not supported by the OS an empty dict is returned.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Is there any version or other distribution of Ubuntu/Linux, which supports thermal sensors?